# Context and Memory leaks

Tags: android

In my application I have a thread and a corresponding handler to update the UI. This thread will be started from my main activity, and the Thread takes several parameters, including a context. This context is used this way:

```
Context c;
MessageHandler handler;

public BluetoothCommunicator(Context c) {
   this.c = c;
   handler = new MessageHandler(c);
}
```

In my `run()` method I post some data to this handler, when a special event has occured. In my `handleMessage()` method I create some ProgressDialogs, in order to inform the user that a operation is ongoing.

```
@Override
    public void handleMessage(Message m) {

        String message = (String) m.obj;

        //Getting files
        if (message.equals("0")) {

            folder.appendToLogFile(new Date().toString(), "Incoming File From: " + deviceName); 

            pd = new ProgressDialog(c);
            pd.setTitle("Please Wait..");
            pd.setMessage("Retrieving file from " + deviceName);
            pd.setCancelable(false);

            pd.show();
        }
```

As I understand I cannot create a ProgressDialog with `getApplicationContext()`, but I need the `Activity Context`.

The way I coded this will cause a memory leak in my applicaion, according to [MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/)

[image]

The way I see this trace is that the `c` corresponds the the object `c` I initalize in my constructor. Is this right?

How can I go around this problem? No an AsyncTask is not relevant because the problem is in the `Context`.

Comment: Do you want to get the context of an activity that is on top of stack? (so that you can show the dialog box on that activity?)

Comment: Thats correct. I start my thread from my main activity, and the progress dialog should also appear on top of this activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the Thread finishes (ie: the `run()` method is complete) just set variable `c` to null. That should take care of your memory leak.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `WeakReference<Context>` object to store weak reference to `Context` of your activity instead of plain reference. This will allow GC to "collect" your activity and will not cause memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

David'd answer will solve your problem, You can also try:

start a dummy activity from handler that will show your progress dialog (You can do it by using custom dialog with `setContentView()` as the layout that you want to show in progress dialog. Also set the theme for this dummy activity as `android:style/Theme.Dialog`). And after your progress dialog finishes or user presses cancel, you finish this dummy activity as well.